# Create Sales Rule With Subtotal condition

Tags: magento2, coupon, sales-rule

I know how to create a sales rule.

But i'm failing to add this rule a condition based on the subtotal

Which means i Want to reproduce this programmatically

[image: need]

I see this is added into the salesrule condition serialized as below

[image: serialized]

But now I would like to know how to update this code to create that condition programmatically.

```
                $rule = $this->ruleFactory->create()->setName($coupon['name'])
                    ->setDescription($coupon['desc'])
                    ->setFromDate($coupon['start'])
                    ->setToDate($coupon['end'])
                    ->setUsesPerCustomer($coupon['max_redemptions'])
                    ->setCustomerGroupIds($customerGroupIds)
                    ->setIsActive(1)
                    ->setSimpleAction($coupon['discount_type'])
                    ->setDiscountAmount($coupon['discount_amount'])
                    ->setDiscountQty(0)
                    ->setApplyToShipping($coupon['flag_is_free_shipping'])
                    ->setTimesUsed($coupon['redemptions'])
                    ->setWebsiteIds($websiteIds)
                    ->setCouponType(2)
                    ->setCouponCode($coupon['code'])
                    ->setUsesPerCoupon($coupon['max_used']);
                $rule->save();
```

I'm unable to find the way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, you must instance the class:

- Magento\SalesRule\Api\Data\ConditionInterfaceFactory;

After that you can do the following:

```
    $newRule = $this->rule->create();
    $actionCondition = $this->conditionInterfaceFactory->create();

    $condition1 = $this->conditionInterfaceFactory->create();
    $condition1 ->setConditionType('\Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule\Condition\Product')
    ->setAttributeName('category_ids')
        ->setOperator('!=')
        ->setValue(175);

    $actionCondition
        ->setAggregatorType(ConditionInterface::AGGREGATOR_TYPE_ANY)
        ->setValue(1)
        ->setConditions([$condition1]);
```

and rule:

```
$newRule->setActionCondition($actionCondition);
```

**Where:
$actionCondition -> 1
$condition1 -> 2**

[image]